# How do I enable support for a cipher in openssh on CentOS?

Tags: centos, openssh

Context: I'm following [a guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-dotnet-core-linux-with-ssh?view=vs-2019) to debug a .NET application running on a CentOS 7 virtual machine from Windows through SSH. And I know almost nothing about SSH on nix.

Problem: VS complained that it couldn't found any common cipher to communicate with the CentOS SSH server. I randomly selected one diffie-hellman and put it inside `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` like so: `Ciphers diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256`. After that I try starting the daemon again and get this error:

```
> systemctl status sshd.service
● sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon                                                                                                                                           
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)                                                                                        
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-04-19 17:32:27 +07; 11s ago                                                                              
     Docs: man:sshd(8)                                                                                                                                                           
           man:sshd_config(5)                                                                                                                                                    
  Process: 3077 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=255)                                                                                                   
 Main PID: 3077 (code=exited, status=255)                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                 
Apr 19 17:32:27 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: sshd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a                                                                 
Apr 19 17:32:27 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenSSH server daemon.                                                                                         
Apr 19 17:32:27 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit sshd.service entered failed state.                                                                                        
Apr 19 17:32:27 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: sshd.service failed.
```

Checking service status give me more info:

```
> systemctl status sshd
Apr 19 17:34:34 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting OpenSSH server daemon...
-- Subject: Unit sshd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit sshd.service has begun starting up.
Apr 19 17:34:34 localhost.localdomain sshd[3083]: /etc/ssh/sshd_config line 29: Bad SSH2 cipher spec 'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256'.
Apr 19 17:34:34 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: sshd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Apr 19 17:34:34 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenSSH server daemon.
-- Subject: Unit sshd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit sshd.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Apr 19 17:34:34 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit sshd.service entered failed state.
Apr 19 17:34:34 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: sshd.service failed.
```

What should I do to enable VS to connect to CentOS?

Comment: available cipher are listed using `ssh -Q cipher`.

Comment: @Archemar The available ciphers don't look like anything VS2019 has, can I download one?